# Why are there two sets of arguments/parenthesis in this Scala method definition?

Tags: scala, syntax

I am new to Scala and am doing some readings around ScalaSTM.

I would appreciate if someone could simply name the concept below, whereby there are 2 sets of brackets being passed to the method.:

```
def transfer(amount: Int, a: Ref[Int], b: Ref[Int])(c: Transaction) {
  a.:=(a.get(c) - amount)(c)
  b.:=(b.get(c) + amount)(c)
}
```

What concept is being employed within `c: Transaction`?

I will read further once I know what I am looking for!

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915027/two-ways-of-currying-in-scala-whats-the-use-case-for-each/4916606#4916606

Comment: Hint: hover over the "Scala tag" and click on the ["info" link](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info). The term here is "Multiple parameter lists".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Two ways of currying in Scala; what's the use-case for each?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915027/two-ways-of-currying-in-scala-whats-the-use-case-for-each)

Answer (score 35):

This is named `Currying`. A curried function is when it has the type A => B => C.

The function `def foo(a: A, b: B): C` has the type `(A, B) => C`.
On the other hand, the function `def curriedFoo(a: A)(b: B): C` has the type `A => B => C`. With the curried function you could do `def curriedFooWithA = curriedFoo(a)` which has the type `B => C`. You don't have to provide all the argument in one go.

So, in your case you can provide the `amount`, `a`, and `b`. You'll get a function taking a `Transaction`. Another case would be a function of the type `Request => DataBase => Int`, where you just provide the `Request`, and finally when you really need to run the request, provide the `DataBase` to which the request has to be sent.

The type `(A, B) => C` and `A => B => C` are isomorphic. Scala provides the `tupled` and `uncurried` that do just that.

`def curriedFoo(a: A)(b: B): C = a => b => foo(a, b)`

`def foo(a: A, b: B): C => (a, b) => curriedFoo(a, b)`