# Scala list error

Tags: list, scala, typing

After a lot of Java and some Haskell I wanted to have a look at Scala. From the code below, I'm getting this error message

`type mismatch; found : List[Nothing] => Option[Nothing] required: List[Int] => Option[Nothing]`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong:

```
object MyFirstScalaObject {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
      lazy val testValues:List[List[Int]] = List((1 to 10).toList, null, List());

      println(  testFunction(last, testValues));
  }

  def testFunction[I, O](f : I => O, inputs : List[I]):
      List[(I, O)] = 
    inputs.zip(inputs.map(f));

  def last[A](xs:List[A]):Option[A] = xs match {
    case x::Nil => Some(x);
    case _::xs => last(xs);
    case _ => None;
  }

}
```

Thanks for any advice.

Cheers,

Comment: You could define `testFunction` as `testFunction[I, O](inputs : List[I])(f: I => O)` and use it as `testFunction(testValues)(last)`.

Comment: senia, I think you should make this into an answer, and the OP should IMHO accept it.

Comment: @Blaisorblade: I've posted it as an answer. But it's "how", not "why".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

because of the way type inference works in scala, it is unable to determine the what the type parameter to `last` has to be, so it has to take the overly conservative fallback guess that it is `Nothing`.

You can explicitly specify the types when you call `testFunction`:

```
testFunction[List[Int],Option[Int](last, testValues)
```

or you can document more fully the relationship between the type parameters in the `testFunction` declaration, which will give the type inferencer more information:

```
def testFunction[A, I[_], O[_]](f : I[A] => O[A], inputs : List[I[A]]): List[(I[A], O[A])]
```

This explicitly says that I and O are type constructors (kind * -> *), now that the input/output types of f are more specific, the inferencer can correctly infer that the A parameter to the the last function must be Int.

Comment: neither the function-call typing, nor the typecontructing-types at the function defintion. Error message is: know it requires "List[Int] => Option[Int]" and assumes that there is just "List[Nothing] => Option[Nothing]". May it be an inpact of the containing "null"-value in the textValues-List?

Comment: user1905015: null values are not a problem; they wouldn't affect type inference for testValues, and anyway type inference is not happening since you're specifying the full type anyway.
stew: type inference is not inferring A in time.

Answer (score 1):

A fully revised & tested version, using senia's idea:

```
object MyFirstScalaObject {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
      lazy val testValues = List((1 to 10).toList, null, List())
      println(testFunction(testValues)(last))
  }

  def testFunction[I, O](inputs: List[I])(f: I => O): List[(I, O)] =
    inputs.zip(inputs.map(f))

  def last[A](xs: List[A]): Option[A] = xs match {
    case x :: Nil => Some(x)
    case _ :: xs => last(xs)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

Type inference proceeds left-to-right; information from one parameter list is used within next parameter list.
In this code, when you call `testFunction` Scala can deduce `I` from the first parameter, then it can feed `I` as the input type of the function `f` to figure out its type (that is, that the argument `last` is applied with `A = Int`), then it finally gets the value of `O` from the return type of the function.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you why type inference in scala works this way.

But there is [common way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4916606/406435) to help compiler in such cases - `parameter sections`.

```
def testFunction[I, O](inputs : List[I])(f: I => O): List[(I, O)] = inputs.zip(inputs.map(f))
```

Usage:

```
testFunction(testValues)(last)
```

Similar solution is to add method `testFunction` to class `List`:

```
class LastsHelper[T](inputs: List[T]) {
  def testFunction[O](f: T => O): List[(T, O)] = inputs.zip(inputs.map(f))
}
implicit def toLastsHelper[T](inputs: List[T]) = new LastsHelper(inputs)
```

You can use such methods like methods of `List`:

```
testValues.testFunction(last)
```