# understanding scala : currying

Tags: scala, currying

I recently started learning Scala and came across currying. From an answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768686/currying-example-in-scala), this code snippet

```
def sum(a: Int)(b: Int) = a + b
```

expands out to this

```
def sum(a: Int): Int => Int = b => a + b
```

Then I saw a snippet from [scala-lang](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/automatic-closures.html), which shows it's possible to write something like this to emulate a while loop

```
  def whileLoop (cond : => Boolean) (body : => Unit) : Unit = {
      if (cond) {
          body
          whileLoop (cond) (body)
      }
  }
```

Out of curiosity, I tried to expand this out, and got this

```
  def whileLoop2 (cond : => Boolean) : (Unit => Unit) =
      (body : => Unit) =>
          if (cond) {
              body
              whileLoop2 (cond) (body)
          }
```

But there seems to be some syntax that I'm missing because I get an error

```
error: identifier expected but '=>' found.
(body : => Unit) => 
        ^
```

What is the proper way to expand out the emulated while loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tricky part is dealing with the parameterless function or "thunk" type `=> Unit`. Here is my version:

```
def whileLoop2 (cond: => Boolean): (=> Unit) => Unit =
  body =>
    if (cond) {
      body
      whileLoop2 (cond)(body)
    }

var i = 5
val c = whileLoop2(i > 0)
c { println(s"loop $i"); i -= 1 }
```

It appears that you can annotate the return type with `(=> Unit) => Unit`, but you cannot annotate `(body: => Unit)`, so you have to rely on the type inference here.

Comment: Is it possible change this solution such that i can write

whileLoop2 (i > 0) { println "..." }

instead of 

whileLoop2(i > 0) { () => println "..." }

? The example in the scala-lang page doesn't have the extra () => bit when using their emulated while loop.

Comment: Sorry, it _is_ possible to use parameterless function arguments. See my edited version.