# how to interpret RDD.treeAggregate

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, distributed-computing

I ran into [this line](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/01f09b161217193b797c8c85969d17054c958615/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/optimization/GradientDescent.scala#L236-L248) in the Apache Spark code source

```
val (gradientSum, lossSum, miniBatchSize) = data
    .sample(false, miniBatchFraction, 42 + i)
    .treeAggregate((BDV.zeros[Double](n), 0.0, 0L))(
      seqOp = (c, v) => {
        // c: (grad, loss, count), v: (label, features)
        val l = gradient.compute(v._2, v._1, bcWeights.value, Vectors.fromBreeze(c._1))
        (c._1, c._2 + l, c._3 + 1)
      },
      combOp = (c1, c2) => {
        // c: (grad, loss, count)
        (c1._1 += c2._1, c1._2 + c2._2, c1._3 + c2._3)
      }
    )
```

I have multiple trouble reading this :

- First I can't find anything on the web that explains exactly how `treeAggregate` works, what are the meaning of the params.
- Second, here `.treeAggregate` seems to have two ()() following the method name. What could that mean? Is that some special scala syntax that I don't understand.
- Finally, I see both seqOp and comboOp return a 3 element tuple which match the expected left hand side variable, but which one actually gets returned?

This statement must be really advanced. I can't begin to decipher this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`treeAggregate` is a specialized implementation of `aggregate` that iteratively applies the combine function to a subset of partitions. This is done in order to prevent returning all partial results to the driver where a single pass reduce would take place as the classic `aggregate` does.

For all practical purposes, `treeAggregate` follows the same principle as `aggregate` explained in this answer: [Explain the aggregate functionality in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240706/explain-the-aggregate-functionality-in-spark-using-python/28241948#28241948) with the exception that it takes an extra parameter to indicate the depth of the partial aggregation level.

Let me try to explain what's going on here specifically:

For aggregate, we need a zero, a combiner function and a reduce function. 
`aggregate` uses [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26108959/understanding-scala-currying) to specify the zero value independently of the combine and reduce functions.

We can then dissect the above function like this . Hopefully that helps understanding:

```
val Zero: (BDV, Double, Long) = (BDV.zeros[Double](n), 0.0, 0L)
val combinerFunction: ((BDV, Double, Long), (??, ??)) => (BDV, Double, Long)  =  (c, v) => {
        // c: (grad, loss, count), v: (label, features)
        val l = gradient.compute(v._2, v._1, bcWeights.value, Vectors.fromBreeze(c._1))
        (c._1, c._2 + l, c._3 + 1)
val reducerFunction: ((BDV, Double, Long),(BDV, Double, Long)) => (BDV, Double, Long) = (c1, c2) => {
        // c: (grad, loss, count)
        (c1._1 += c2._1, c1._2 + c2._2, c1._3 + c2._3)
      }
```

Then we can rewrite the call to `treeAggregate` in a more digestable form:

```
val (gradientSum, lossSum, miniBatchSize) = treeAggregate(Zero)(combinerFunction, reducerFunction)
```

This form will 'extract' the resulting tuple into the named values `gradientSum, lossSum, miniBatchSize` for further usage.

Note that `treeAggregate` takes an additional parameter [`depth`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1150) which is declared with a default value `depth = 2`, thus, as it's not provided in this particular call, it will take that default value.