# I've got some problems on understanding spark LBFGS treeAggregate transformation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, non-linear-regression

I'm trying to use spark LBFGS method in my project recently, but when I read source code ,I realy got a big problem, here is the code:
[the code I don't understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZF46A.png)
and here is the source code link:https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.0/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/optimization/LBFGS.scala

My problem is : If my input data(label, feature) only contains label and feature vectors, how does treeAggregate seqOp able to match{ case ((grad, loss), (label, features)}? I thought it can only match {case (label, features)}。

And in fact ，I'm not really understand "treeAggregate" either, can someone help me ?

Comment: see here [how to interpret RDD.treeAggregate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860635/how-to-interpret-rdd-treeaggregate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are not **really** understood `treeAggregate operation`.

**In you post picture, let me give you a `thorough description` about your problem.**

**After that you will understand why the source code can match the things correctly!**

If you find `treeAggregate` confusing, you can first understand the simple but similar version of it - `aggregate`.

The prototype of aggregate is:

```
def aggregate[U](zeroValue: U)(seqOp: (U, T) ⇒ U, combOp: (U, U) ⇒ U)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): U
```

It seems **complex**, right? Let me clarify it for you:

RDD provides abstraction for physically distributed data in many partitions, **so how can we aggregate the values for one specific key**?

It obviously has two situations:

1. **merge one value in same partition**.
2. **merge data across different partitions**.

---

```
seqOp: (U, V) ⇒ U
```

This is exactly operation **how can values be merged in the one partition result**.

```
combOp: (U, U) ⇒ U
```

This is **across partitions merge operation**!

I guess you are familiar with the `reduce` operation.

In fact, `aggregate` operation is more general that `reduce` operation.

Why `aggregate` exists is that sometimes **we need to "reduce" the values for a unique key, but want to get the result in a different type from they are in parent rdd**.

For example, what if we want to find for one specific key in parent rdd, how many unique values with it?

this "reduce" operation's value type is obviously different from the parent rdd.

```
val pairs = sc.parallelize(Array(("a", 3), ("a", 1), ("b", 7), ("a", 5)))
val sets = pairs.aggregateByKey(new HashSet[Int])(_+_, _++_)
sets.collect
res0: Array[(String, scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[Int])]  =Array((b,Set(7)), (a,Set(1, 5, 3))
```

The example is about **aggregateByKey**, but it is understandable for **aggregate**, just using whole data aggregate, not about different key.

**That's all**.