# how to set target feature dimension in Spark MLLIb's HashingTF() function?

Tags: hash, hashtable, apache-spark-mllib, tf-idf

Apache Spark MLLIB has HashingTF() function which takes tokenized words as input and converts those sets 
into fixed-length feature vectors.

As mentioned in documentation link
[spark mlib documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html)

it is advisable to use power of two as the feature dimension.

The question is whether the exponent value is the number of terms in the input

If yes, Suppose If I consider more than 1000 text document as input which has more than 5000 terms , then the feature dimension become 2^5000

Whether my assumption is correct or is there any other way to find exponent value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to interpret RDD.treeAggregate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860635/how-to-interpret-rdd-treeaggregate)

Answer (score 1):

From the document [HashingTF](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.HashingTF) it said: "it is advisable to use power of two as the feature dimension" --> I think it means numFeatures = 2^n

For example your vocabulary size is 900, then numFeatures value should be > 900 and a power of two, which is 2^10 (=1024) could be a good estimate.

Comment: You should provide a link to the documentation if you are giving its reference.

Comment: Thanks, I added the link to document