# Currying function from an existing answer is invalid

Tags: scala

I tried running the below code:

```
val f: (a: Int) => (b: Int) => (c: Int) = a + b + c
```

found in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915027/two-ways-of-currying-in-scala-whats-the-use-case-for-each) in the REPL and IntellijIDEA but it's apparently invalid.

From the REPL:

```
scala> val f: (a: Int) => (b: Int) => (c: Int) = a + b + c
<console>:1: error: ')' expected but ':' found.
       val f: (a: Int) => (b: Int) => (c: Int) = a + b + c
                ^
```

Anyone knows why? My scala version is 2.10.1

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write the type as if you were writing:

```
val a: 5 = 5
```

What you want is more like

```
val f  = (a: Int) => (b: Int) => (c: Int) => a+b+c
```

To elaborate further the REPL will write

```
f: Int => (Int => (Int => Int)) = <function1>
```

Because function definition is right associative you could the type of f explicitly as follows

```
f: Int => Int => Int => Int = (a: Int) => (b: Int) => (c: Int) => a+b+c
```

If you explicitly give the function type like this the compiler does not need information about what a,b, and c are and you could simply write a => b => c => a+b+c instead.