# Difference between these two scala function definitions

Tags: scala

I am going through the Scala School basics tutorial at
https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/basics.html.

I am trying to understand what the difference between these two definitions is.

Also, if someone could explain currying vs partial application in this context.

`def multiply(m: Int)(n: Int): Int = m * n`

and

`def multiply(m: Int,n: Int): Int = m * n`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Two ways of currying in Scala; what's the use-case for each?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915027/two-ways-of-currying-in-scala-whats-the-use-case-for-each)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is only in how you actually call this methods. In *second* case your only choice is to pass both arguments at the same time, like `multiply(2,2)`. In `first` case you can pass one argument and get function `Int => Int` and then call it with another argument:

```
val f: Int => Int = multiply(2) _

f(2) // 4
f(3) // 6
f(525) // 1050
```

The real power of curried methods is when the second argument is implicit so you don't have to pass it explicitly.

```
implicit val x = 2
def multiply(m: Int)(implicit n: Int): Int = m * n

multiply(5) //10
```

Comment: Ok. That sort of makes sense now. I can see that. Just trying to connect the dots in my head. How is the first definition different from this
`code`def multiply2(a:Int) = { b:Int => a * b }`code`
I am new to scala so excuse my being dense. How would you read this in english might help me make sense of it

Comment: @user1299508, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915027/two-ways-of-currying-in-scala-whats-the-use-case-for-each