# Scala method overloading with generics

Tags: scala, generics, overloading

Sample code with two overload method compiles (Scala 2.11.8), as expected:

```
def foo(p: Int, t: Double): Unit = {}
def foo(r: Int => Double): Unit = {}

foo(0, 0) // 1st method
foo(x => x.toDouble) // 2nd method
```

Same code with generic parameter added:

```
def fooGeneric[T](p: T, t: Double): Unit = {}
def fooGeneric[T](r: T => Double): Unit = {}

fooGeneric[Int](1, 1) // 1st method
fooGeneric[Int]((x: Int) => x.toDouble) //2nd method

fooGeneric[Int](x => x.toDouble) // does not compile
```

yields the following compilation error:

```
Error:(112, 19) missing parameter type
fooGeneric[Int](x => x.toDouble)
```

There seems to be is no ambiguity in the method resolution, yet compiler fails to find the match. Why?

Comment: It seems there is an interaction between overload resolution and type inference. This very recent [SI-10074](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-10074) reports this very issue.

Comment: Sidenote that does not answer your question: the latest version of [Dotty](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty) compiles your example without any complaints.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4916606/4496364

Comment: The following compiles - `fooGeneric[Int]{ x: Int => x.toDouble }`

Comment: You could do this but not ideal I guess - `def fooGeneric[T, U <: Double](r: T => U): Unit = {}` then `fooGeneric[Int, Double](x => x.toDouble)`

Comment: @Nio Yes, adding a phantom generic type solves the problem. A bit hacky, though :)